# Redmine plugin: model not found, I have to copy to core app/models

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

I am using Redmine 2.0.3. I developed a custom plugin called cg_process.

Inside the directory plugins/cg_process/app/models/ there is the model file called "ProjectInfo.rb".

When I use the plugin, Redmine cannot find the model.

It gives the following error:

```
Started GET "/project_infos/new?project_id=master-prj-setup" for 172.18.56.10 at Fri Jul 06 09:36:59 +0000 2012
Processing by ProjectInfosController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"project_id"=>"master-prj-setup"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 12ms

NameError (uninitialized constant ProjectInfosController::ProjectInfo):
  plugins/cg_process/app/controllers/project_infos_controller.rb:32:in `new'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:469:in `_run__755186413__process_action__943997142__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `send'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `send'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:206:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `action'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
  rack-openid (1.3.1) lib/rack/openid.rb:98:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__397314981__call__4__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `send'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `send'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  passenger (2.2.14) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:92:in `process_request'
  passenger (2.2.14) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:207:in `main_loop'
  passenger (2.2.14) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:120:in `run'
  passenger (2.2.14) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:65:in `spawn_application'
  passenger (2.2.14) lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:252:in `safe_fork'
  passenger (2.2.14) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:58:in `spawn_application'
  passenger (2.2.14) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:41:in `spawn_application'
  passenger (2.2.14) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:159:in `spawn_application'
  passenger (2.2.14) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:287:in `handle_spawn_application'
  passenger (2.2.14) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `__send__'
  passenger (2.2.14) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `main_loop'
  passenger (2.2.14) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:196:in `start_synchronously'
  passenger (2.2.14) bin/passenger-spawn-server:61
```

If I copy the model file ProjectInfo.rb from the plugin directory (plugins/cg_process/app/models/) to the core directory (app/models), everything works well.

Temporarily I made a fix in the capistrano deploy file, in order to copy the model file to the core directory. But this is just a workaround. I would like to find a standard solution.

I cannot understand why Redmine cannot find the model inside the plugin directory.

Probably I am missing something, but I cannot figure out what.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are trying to create a redmine plugin model. So run

```
rails generate redmine_plugin_model <plugin_name> <model_name>
```

That is

```
rails generate redmine_plugin_model cg_process project_info
```

Then Edit migration file and add fields, run

```
 rake redmine:plugins:migrate
```